# Why I get no results filtering with Django?

Tags: django, django-filter

I am trying to filter some of data and I use django filter to do it.

One of my model fields is a Foreign Key, which automatically `ModelChoiceFilter` is used. In my case I need to choose more than one option from the specific filter so I use `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter`.

A `queryset` parameter needs to be passed in`ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` if you manually instantiated it.

I am trying to achieve this using the code below, but I get no results using the specific filter. Although I get the proper results from the other filters:

**filters.py**

```
def available_bookies(request):
    """ Return available bookies
        for current user
    """
    if request is None:
        return Bet.objects.none()

    user = request.user
    return Bet.objects.filter(user=user).values_list("bookie__name", flat=True).distinct()



class BetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    # Some other filters

    bookie = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=available_bookies)

    class Meta:
        model = Bet
        fields = ["date_from", "date_to", "odds_from", "odds_to",
                  "stake_from", "stake_to", "country_multi",
                  "competition_multi", "sport_multi", "status_multi",
                  "home_multi", "visitor_multi", "bookie"]


    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super(BetFilter, self).qs
        return parent.order_by("-timestamp")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your filter field gets a queryset. The callable you've written returns a list so I suspect that to be your issue because what you have done matches the [docs](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter). So try to adjust it to return a queryset;

```
def available_bookies(request):
    """ Return available bookies
        for current user
    """
    if request is None:
        return Bet.objects.all()
    if request.user:
        user = request.user
        return Bet.objects.filter(user=user)

    return Bet.objects.all()
```

You can provide a `method` attribute to your filters which customises how the filter for that field works. I do this for a few of mine, so you'd do something like this to filter on the user at that point;

```
class BetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # Some other filters

    bookie = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        label=_("Bookie"),
        method='bookie_filter',
        queryset=Bet.objects.all()
    )

    def bookie_filter(self, qs, name, value):
        """
        Override the filter method in order to lookup for more than one field.

        :param qs:
        :param name:
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        if not value:
            return qs

        if self.request.user:
            return qs.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                bookie__name=value
            )

        return qs.filter(name=value)
```

Comment: I tried your answer and the bookie filter does not display any options to choose from.

Comment: That's probably because your queryset returns a list of values rather than a queryset I suspect. Try to just return the filter.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou Updated my answer. You can't do `Bet.objects.none()` like I suggested because then you're filtering on an empty queryset. I've revisited it, however this effects the result after a value is selected from the choices and you want to limit the choices to begin with?

Comment: @GiannisIordanou Looking back at your code, I think the issue was the fact you return a list when it needs a queryset, so take a look at my update.

Comment: I believe that the code for the callable and the code for the method are separate ways to do it. Using the callable, the options on the filter are the `__str__` method of the model.

Comment: @GiannisIordanou that's right, they are separate. The callable for the queryset is what you want. And it needs to return a queryset, so does returning `Bet.objects.filter(user=user)` work?

Comment: The `Bet.objects.filter(user=user)` gets returned but in the filter the available options are the `__str__` method of the model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165349/discussion-between-markwalker-and-giannisiordanou).